# How to get the port number a user ssh'd in on?

Tags: ssh, monitoring, port, user-management

I am transitioning servers away from port 22 in an existing multiuser environment.  I have configured sshd to listen on two ports: 22 and the new port.

Now I would like to detect when a user connects or is connected to port 22.  This is apparently harder than I anticipated.

I tried cranking up the logging in sshd_config but even DEBUG doesn't record the port number.

I am currently scanning netstat's output for TCP connections to port 22 but that lists a hell of a lot of false positives from random bot scanners. [the reason for the port move]

Comment: Why do you have false positive on port 22 ? Please provide `netstat -anp | grep :22`

Comment: The false positive is from scripts connecting to port 22. I want users that have successfully authenticated on port 22.

Comment: Ah aha.   netstat -anp | grep :22 does have a tipoff if the connection is for a shell. The 7th field will end in a ':' and you can tease out the connecting port from the 4th field.  AWK script in progress.

Comment: Create a separate config file for port 22 and configure it to log to LOCAL6. Then add a local6.* directive to /etc/(r)syslog.conf and restart it. run /usr/sbin/sshd -f newconfig file. The sshd on port 22 will now be logging to a separate file.

Comment: I went with this:
`sudo netstat -tnp | awk '$4 ~ /:22$/ && $7 ~ /sshd:$/ {users[$8]++} END {for (u in users) printf "%s:%s\n",u,users[u];}'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `lsof -n -i TCP:22 -a -c sshd -a -u ^root,^sshd` you can get a list of `sshd` processes and user names with their sockets on port 22. It is skipping those owned by `root` or `sshd` because they do not correspond to logged in users.

A completely different approach would be to add some commands to `/etc/ssh/sshrc`, which will parse `$SSH_CONNECTION` and log it:
`logger -p auth.notice -t "sshd[$$]" "$SSH_CONNECTION"`

A third approach is to create a second instance of `sshd` for port 22 and configure it to log to a different facility.

Comment: Your second approach was something I was already working on.

Comment: Add this: `netstat -tnp | awk '$7 ~ /sshd:$/ {sub(/.*:/,"",$4); print $8, $4}'`

Comment: Add this: Append `logger -p auth.notice -t sshd[$$] $SSH_ENVIRONMENT` to /etc/profile

Comment: You could put it in /etc/ssh/sshrc instead of /etc/profile.

Comment: Actually - lsof still shows attempted connections not authenticated ones. Adding a logging command to the login scripts might be the only way to go.

Comment: @DanGarthwaite You should be able to tell the difference between connections that are authenticated and those that are not by looking at the username. Have you found a case, where that does not work?

Comment: I'd vote for the third approach.

Comment: It doesn't work if root is allowed to login. *shudder*.  But that is nit picking - this answer is much improved.  Thanks.

Comment: `-p auth.notice` isn't logged by default in ubuntu... I went with `-p info`.  Also a ssh reload is required. It helps to also log $USER before $SSH_CONNECTION so you know who to email about reconfiguring their ssh client.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
sudo lsof -i -n -P | egrep sshd.*ESTABLISHED | egrep `who -a|grep pts|awk '{print $7}'|sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\|/g'`
```

To clarify, the objective of this command is to match the `lsof` hits (which show the port used) with the sessions from `who` with `pts` (extracting the PIDs from the output) in order to filter out the false positives.

In other words, it shows the connections from the processes with the PIDs holding a pts ssh session.

Comment: Didn't work on my ubuntu machine, but lsof -i -n -P is certainly parseable.

Comment: Yeah, it will depend on the output format for each one of the commands (lsof and who). I used this in an Oracle Linux 6 Server. Just tested on Fedora 20 too and it works.

Comment: To list the owners of the current open connections to port 22, just use lsof:
sudo lsof -i :22 -a -u ^sshd -a -c sshd -a -sTCP:ESTABLISHED

There's no need to complicate it with several greps, pipes, awk and sed.

Comment: Wouldn't that also show the false positives mentioned in the comments from the question?